# PHP - Fetch the values of a specific key from an associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to get the value of a specific key in an array or string format, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

So, this is an example of an array I'm working with, for example, I'm trying to get all the `product_id`'s in a single array or string format.

Like output  `productIdArray[] = ['34441', '34442' , '34444'];`

Tried achieving this using for each but, Is there a better way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
(
    [0] => ( Array
                (
                    [id] => 1333708
                    [abc_id] => 429084
                    [test_id] => 58291
                    [order_id] => 2222
                    [product_id] => 34441
                )
        )
    [1] => ( Array
                (
                    [id] => 1333708
                    [abc_id] => 429084
                    [test_id] => 58291
                    [order_id] => 2222
                    [product_id] => 34442
                )
        )
     [2] => ( Array
                (
                    [id] => 1333708
                    [abc_id] => 429084
                    [test_id] => 58291
                    [order_id] => 2222
                    [product_id] => 34444
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `array_column`

```
$res = array_column($arr,'product_id');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lessmore. It worked like a charm.